# Split a large flat file by first two characters on each line

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a large file ~10 GB that is comma delimited.  Each row starts with a 2 character code that tells what type of row it is as each row is a different type of event.  Currently I read the file into R, then use a regex to split it into different pieces based on code then write the resulting objects to a flat file.

I'm curious if there's a more direct way to do this (read a row, determine row type and append the row to the appropriate flat file (there will be 7 total)) in Python, bash, sed/awk, etc.

Data looks like this:

```
01,tim@bigcompany.com,20140101120000,campaign1
02,201420140101123000,123321,Xjq12090,TX
02,201420140101123000,123321,Xjq12090,AK
...
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `grep "^01" file > 01.txt`

Comment: @mark-setchell : This will read the whole huge file n times. In this particular case, it will read 70 GB instead of 10GB!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F, '{fn=$1 ".txt"; print > fn}' file
```

If you want to keep it clean by closing all file handles in the end use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, '!($1 in files){files[$1]=$1 ".txt"} {print > files[$1]}
    END {for (f in files) close(files[$f])}' file
```

Comment: All the files are closed when the script ends anyway, why are you closing them in the `END` block ? Wouldn't it be cleaner to do `{print > files[$1];close(files[$1])}` ?

Comment: Well if awk is auto closing all files then first command is also fine. I read somewhere that older awk versions didn't do it automatically hence I gave 2nd command as an alternative. Also `{print > files[$1];close(files[$1])}` will close file after every line and will not be efficient for ~10GB of data.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about performance, or trust your OS/filesystem/drive's disk caching:

```
with open('hugedata.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        with open(line[:2] + '.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

However, constantly reopening and reclosing (and therefore flushing) the files is going to mean you never get the benefit of buffering, and there's only so much a disk cache can do to make up for that, so, you might want to consider pre-opening all the files. Since there are only 7 of them, that's pretty easy:

```
files = { format(i, '{:02}'): open(format(i, '{:02}.txt'), 'w') for i in range(1, 8)}
try:
    with open('hugedata.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            files[line[:2]].write(line)
finally:
    for file in files:
        file.close()
```

Or, more robustly:

```
files = collections.defaultdict(lambda s: open(s+'.txt', 'w'))
try:
    with open('hugedata.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:                
            files[line[:2]].write(line)
finally:
    for file in files:
        file.close()
```

(You can write a `with` statement that does the closing automatically, but it'll be different in different Python versions; this is a bit clunky, but works with everything from 2.4 to 3.5, and probably beyond, and since you haven't told us your platform or Python version, it seemed safer.)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this in Python:

```
for line in file('hugedata.txt'):
    fh = file(line[:2] + '.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(line)
```

Comment: I don't think you want to open files and just leak them. Especially if you're going to be reopening them a fraction of a millisecond later. Also, don't use `file` unless you need to work with Python 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
grep '^01' your-10gb-file > 01.csv
```

You can then wrap this inside a foreach (for tcsh) like this:

```
foreach n ( `seq -f '%02g' 7` )
    grep '^$n' your-10gb-file > $n.csv
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("largefile.txt") as f:
    for k,v in groupby(f,lambda x: x[:2]):
        with open("{}.txt".format(k),"w") as f1:
            f1.writelines(v)
```